# Newbie prob after installing QT - error: unknown type name 'QApplication'

Tags: c++, qt

After having a hard time installing Qt5.10.0 on Ubuntu 18 I managed to keep a HelloWorld running. The whole process of creating has been done by Qt. What I don't understand:

in main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

In the 'Issues window' of Qt Creator I get:

```
In line 6: QApplication a(argc, argv);
/home/joachim/Versuch/Test_2_HelloWorld/main.cpp:6: error: unknown type name 'QApplication'


In line 7: MainWindow w;
/home/joachim/Versuch/Test_2_HelloWorld/main.cpp:7: error: variable of type 'MainWindow' has private destructor

In line 8: w.show();
/home/joachim/Versuch/Test_2_HelloWorld/main.cpp:8: error: no member named 'show' in 'MainWindow'
```

And a lot of other errors in other files as well. These are serious errors, aren't they? So why is the code running then?

Another question: Why is it so cumbersome to show a block of code on stackoverflow.com, say with [code] and [/code] in between, like it is done in all other coder forums?

Comment: _Another question: Why is it so cumbersome to show a block of code on stackoverflow.com, say with [code] and [/code] in between, like it is done in all other coder forums?_ SO supports a flavor of Markdown. What's wrong with it?

Comment: What happens in `#include "mainwindow.h"`? (It would be better to expose it as well.) Such strange errors may happen e.g. if you forgot to close a namespace in that header. Alternatively, you could move `#include <QApplication>` to top and look whether errors change.

Comment: The `mainwindow.h` is actually innocent looking. It seems my first suspicion was wrong. My other guess would have been "wrong include paths" but this should give an error concerning the `#include` line itself (and if I remember right no further compiling of this file). However, `unknown type name 'Q_OBJECT'` is very suspiciuos. I must admit I've no experience with Qt Creator - using VS2013 or Notepad++ with `qmake-qt5` on command line (which produces `Makefile`s which I build with `make`). The latter is something you could try alternatively...

Comment: How are these errors "highlighted". Do you see a unfilled, red circle (like a red O) or a filled in, red circle with a small ! inside? This helps to find out whether the error comes from the compiler or the code model

Answer (score 0):

in mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

gives me:

class MainWindow : public
QMainWindow/home/joachim/Versuch/Test_2_HelloWorld/mainwindow.h:10: error: expected class name

Q_OBJECT
/home/joachim/Versuch/Test_2_HelloWorld/mainwindow.h:12: error: unknown type name 'Q_OBJECT'

public:
/home/joachim/Versuch/Test_2_HelloWorld/mainwindow.h:14: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

---

@scheff:

> What's wrong with it?
>   First I ignored this peculiar requirement of stackoverflow. Then I had to figure out what'S going on. Wasting 3min later it worked. Now in this post it doesn't work again. I had to manually indent all lines.
>   That's wrong with it.
>   Und nebenbei, dieser HTML Eingabeeditor ist der letzte Dreck. Der kann keinen richtigen Zeilenumbruch, Shift + return versteht der nicht. Ich hab schon wieder n Blutdruck... Wahrscheinlich geschrieben von den gleichen Typen die vi geschrieben haben, alles auf einer ach so geilen Codebase von Unix Sys V von 1969...

Comment: Is this an answer or an addition to your question? In the latter case, please, use [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54530651/edit) under your question text to modify it. In general, you should have a look at the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). And btw., after some experience with Markdown in SO (and github), I became a real fan and seriously started to write our docs in MD also. I must admit that I've no other experiences in coder forums than here in SO. But, I've seen wrong formatted code in any other forum as well. IMHO it's a question of personal (dis-)like.

Comment: ... Man kann's niemals allen recht machen... ;-) It's a pity to compare Markdown (and the nice little inline editor of this site) with `vi`. I was never able to use `vi` seriously except for `:wq` which was actually all what I needed in any case.

Comment: If you don't like the inline editor at all, you could alternatively write/edit the whole text in your local text editor of choice (which I do sometimes when I'm afraiding a broken connection before ready or to publish accidentally what's not ready) and copy/paste the result finally into the inline editor. Furthermore, whenever Markdown does not exactly what I want (or I do not know how to write in Markdown and am too lazy to google) I do it in HTML.